# Running ArcView Avenue scripting files in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcview-3

Is there any way possible to run ArcView 3.3 Avenue Scripting files (.ave and .avx files) into the newer versions of ArcGIS 10.x?

I am aware that ESRI has stopped supporting ArcView 3.x, but I am still interested to run these scripts. I can view the files using Notepad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No, this is not possible. You need to have ArcView 3.x to run these files.

I seem to remember there used to be an ArcView project importer made by Esri that allowed for ArcView 3.x projects to be imported into ArcGIS Desktop. However I'm not sure (Actually, I'm quite certain) that Avenue code is not converted by the importer.

If you want to run the code, you will probably have to look at the code in Notepad, and translate it manually to whatever language you are comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted to know. Although on ESRI discussion forum, I found this thread about the conversion of ArcView 3.0 to ArcMap 9.2 http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=3&f=39&t=281908&mc=4, What I have noticed that there is no automatic way for this kind of conversion and ultimately user will have to re-write the code. I wanted to know that can we use model builder fucntion to assist in this conversion task anyways?

Comment: Broadly speaking, ArcView 3.x is so different from ArcGIS 10.x that there is no easy translation between them. The best option is a human who understands what the Avenue script was trying to achieve, who can use their knowledge of ArcGIS to re-write the functionality (rather than an automated script which attempts to convert syntax from the old format to a new format)